# Flatness and fibers of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, flatness

I am trying to develop intuition for why a flat map of schemes $f : X \rightarrow Y$ has "continuously varying fibers", and vice versa. Evidently defining what it means for fibers to vary continuously is quite hard, but I am content with working through examples to get a sense of what it means.

Here are my questions:

1) Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ be a map of smooth manifolds. Suppose $C^{\infty}(N ) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ is flat. Is $f$ open?

2) Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a flat map of schemes. Is $f$ an open map?

3) Let $M$ be $1$ dimensional $\{ (t, t^2) : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define a map $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sending $(t, t^2)$ to $t^2$. Is $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ flat?

4) Let $X = \text{Spec}(k[x, y]/ \langle x^2 - y \rangle)$. Let $X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ be the projection map corresponding to the map $k[t] \rightarrow k[x, y]$ sending $t$ to $x^2 = y$. Is $X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ flat?

Comment: Even [understanding whether a submersion is flat is difficult](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1217/are-submersions-of-differentiable-manifolds-flat-morphisms). Flatness is not often used in smooth manifolds, because there are better tools for the job. I would advise that you're barking up the wrong tree here, and also you should probably separate questions 1 and 3 from 2 and 4 - the odds are genuinely difficult, and the evens are trivially easy (no, try Spec of $k[t]\hookrightarrow k(t)$; yes, the morphism of modules $k[t]\to k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ gives the latter as a free module).

Comment: While #2 is false in general, it is true if we assume that $f$ is finite type and the schemes are locally Noetherian.

Comment: Do you know about Miracle Flatness? That if $X$ And $Y$ are regular (or even Cohen-Macaulay) varieties (and let's assume irreducible to avoid headaches) then a map $f:X\to Y$ is flat iff the fiber dimension $f^{-1}(y)$ over closed points are constant. Evidently 'have same fiber dimension' is necessary for the fibers to 'vary continuously'. If you want to see an example where you can make this continuity condition even more literal see Proposition II-29 and Lemma II-30 of Eisenbud and Harris's book *Geometry of Schemes*.

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks, that's interesting!